# Jackson : How to serialize into an unnamed array

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

This is my POJO.

```
public class FolderPage {

private List<ApplicationIcon> applications;

public List<ApplicationIcon> getApplications() {
    return applications;
}

public void setApplications(List<ApplicationIcon> applications) {
    this.applications = applications;
}

@JsonCreator
public FolderPage(List<ApplicationIcon> applications) {
    super();
    this.applications = applications;
}
}
```

Currently it serializes as the below json
    {
        "applications": [{
            "application": {
                "id": "com.microsoft.onenote",
                "name": "Micrsoft OneNote"
            }
        }, {
            "application": {
                "id": "com.microsoft.Office.word",
                "name": "Microsoft word"
            }
        }]
    }

However I want to serialize it into an unnamed json array like the below

```
[{
    "application": {
        "id": "com.microsoft.onenote",
        "name": "Micrsoft OneNote"
    }
}, {
    "application": {
        "id": "com.microsoft.Office.word",
        "name": "Microsoft word"
    }
}]
```

How can I achieve the same?

**EDIT**
POJO representing my application object

```
@JsonRootName("application")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApplicationIcon extends Icon {

    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Serialize `folderPage.getApplications()` instead of the FolderPage object. That looks really obvious.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Serializing `folderPage.getApplication` is giving me unnamed application objects and not just an unnamed application array, `[{"id":"com.microsoft.onenote","name":"Micrsoft OneNote","iconURL":"http://onenote.com"},{"id":"com.microsoft.Office.word","name":"Microsoft word"}]
`. I need an unnamed application array containing named application objects.

Plus `FolderPage` is a part of a bigger POJO and I can't serialize only `folderpage.getApplications`

Comment: It's not possible that you're getting "unnamed" application objects if you serialize `folderPage.getApplications()` but not if you're serializing `folderPage`. It's the same list of  `ApplicationIcon` objects. In any case what you described above is not valid Javascript - and hence, not valid JSON - syntax. A dictionary has keys and values, and a list has only values.  You can't have a dictionary without keys like how you're describing your desired output.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt maybe you could show your code

Comment: @Tiina Sorry? What code?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, There was a typo in my desired output. I didn't mean to wrap my unnamed list in a dict.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Serialization and output got in the 2 cases

`System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(folderPage.getApplications()));`
`[{"id":"com.microsoft.onenote","name":"Micrsoft OneNote","iconURL":"http://onenote.com"},{"id":"com.microsoft.Office.word","name":"Microsoft word"}]`

Comment: `System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(folderPage));`

`{"applications":[{"application":{"id":"com.microsoft.onenote","name":"Micrsoft OneNote","iconURL":"http://onenote.com"}},{"application":{"id":"com.microsoft.Office.word","name":"Microsoft word"}}]}
`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Also added the `Application` POJO in the original description for reference.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The code that if Abhijith runs could get the same result as you said. Because 2nd comments he left shows that what he got is different from yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ApplicationIcon` has `getId()` and `getName()`. You can do it with custom Serializer:

```
public static class FolderPageSearialer extends JsonSerializer<FolderPage> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(FolderPage o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            List<ApplicationIcon> applications = o.getApplications();
            jsonGenerator.writeStartArray(applications.size());
            for (ApplicationIcon application : applications) {
                jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("application");
                jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                jsonGenerator.writeStringField("id", application.getId());
                jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", application.getName());
                jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
                jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
            }
            jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
        }
    }
```

And add @JsonSerialize on FolderPage class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FolderPage.FolderPageSearialer.class)
public class FolderPage
```